# TypeScript outputs ES5 code

Tags: typescript

In typescript, how can I tell the compiler to actually output classes, consts, lets, etc, instead of converting everything to vars and functions? I'm using Typescript 2.4.1.

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2017", /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2015", /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": false, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "es2016",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "alwaysStrict": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Your compiler options look ok, are you sure that is the config being used ?

Comment: Voila! Turns out `tsc MyFile.ts` apparently does not use the tsconfig.json file in the current directory. Put that in an answer if you like.

Answer (score 3):

You have to invoke `tsc` without any input files as parameters for it to use the `tsconfig.json`.

[From the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json`
>   files are ignored.